# User does not keep cookie when they leave the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I'm using jscookie to assign users a cookie after a popup is triggered to ensure that they don't see it again for 7 days. My code is below.

On both pages the function looks for the popup cookie. If the cookie isn't there the popup is triggered and the cookie is assigned. Both of these functions work correctly.

#### Here's the problem:

If the user visits `page A` the popup will trigger and they will be assigned the cookie. Then, if the user goes to `page B` they still have the cookie and the popup will not be triggered.

However, if the user visits `page B` first the popup will be triggered and the cookie is assigned. **But** if the user then goes to `page A` the cookie no longer appears in the cookie list. `page A`'s popup will trigger and the cookie will be assigned.

**Here's the kicker**. If I go back to page B I will see that I have two of the exact same cookie. The only difference is the `path`. One `popup_cookie` from page A and another from page B.

Example:

```
Name          Value  Domain        Path
popup_cookie  true   mydomain.com  /page-a
popup_cookie  true   mydomain.com  /page-b
```

#### Question:

So why is it that the user keeps the cookie when going from `page A` to `page B`, but not from `page B` to `page A`? As you can see below the cookie is being assigned in the same way in both instances.

```
////Page A Popup

// Checks for popup cookie
if (Cookies.get('popup_cookie') == 'true') {
    // Do nothing
} else if ($('#form').length) { 
    $('#form').appendTo('#page-a-popup-container');
    $('body').on('mouseleave',function () {
        if ($('#other-element').hasClass('visible')) {
            // Do nothing
        } else {
            $('#page-a-popup-container').css('display', 'grid');
            $('#popup-bg').fadeIn();
            Cookies.set('popup_cookie', true, {expires: 7, path: ''});
            $('body').off('mouseleave');
        }
    });
    // Pop-up Close Button
    $('#page-a-popup-close').click(function () {
        $('#page-a-popup-container').hide();
        $('#popup-bg').hide();
    });
}

//// Page B Popup

// Checks for popup cookie
if (Cookies.get('popup_cookie') == 'true') {
    // Do nothing
} else if ($('#form').length) {
    $('#form').appendTo('#plan-b-popup-container');
    $('body').on('mouseleave',function () {
        if ($('#drip-header-119587').hasClass('drip-hidden')) {
            // Do nothing
        } else {
            $('#plan-b-popup-container').css('display', 'grid');
            $('#popup-bg').fadeIn();
            Cookies.set('popup_cookie', true, {expires: 7, path: ''});
            $('body').off('mouseleave');
        }
    });
    // Pop-up Close Button
    $('#plan-b-popup-close').click(function () {
        $('#plan-b-popup-container').hide();
        $('#popup-bg').hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. I test it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dangit. Of course I figure it out right after I spend all this time on this post :(

All I had to do what set the cookie's path to `path: '/'` in both functions. That way the cookie assigned on an interior page is kept on every page.

Apparently the path determines where the cookie is active.